# NodeJs routes are no working

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am trying to create an api for login in nodejs.but when i check the login route  via Http requester it showingCannot "POST /api/authenticate"

The project structure:

[image]

server.js file:

```js
var express    = require('express');
var app        = express();
var port       = process.env.PORT||8080;
var morgan     = require('morgan');
var mongoose   = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var router     = express.Router();
var appRoutes  = require('./app/routes/api')(router);
var path       = require('path');

app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json()); 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use('/app',appRoutes);


mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/tutorial', function(err){
 if(err) {
  console.log('Not connected to the Database: '+ err);
 }
 else {
  console.log('Succesfully connected to Mongodb');
 }
});

app.get('*',function(req,res){
     res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/app/views/index.html'));
});

app.listen(port, function () {
 console.log('Running the server on port ' + port);
});
```

/app/models/user.js:

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema   = mongoose.Schema;
var bcrypt   = require('bcrypt-nodejs'); 

var UserSchema = new Schema({
   username: { type: String, lowercase: true, required: true, unique: true },
   password: { type: String, required: true },
   email: { type: String, lowercase: true, required: true, unique: true }

});

UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  var user = this;
  bcrypt.hash(user.password, null, null, function(err, hash) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    user.password = hash;
     next();
});
  next();
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

/app/routes/api.js:

```js
var User       =require('../models/user');

module.exports = function(router) {
  //http://localhost:8080/api/users
  //User Registration Route
  router.post('/users', function(req,res){
    var user = new User();
    user.username = req.body.username;
    user.password = req.body.password;
    user.email    = req.body.email;
  if (req.body.username == null ||  req.body.username == '' || req.body.email == null || req.body.email == ''|| req.body.password == null  || req.body.password == ''  ){
    res.send('Ensure Username, Email and Password is provided');
  
  } else {
        user.save(function(err){
      if(err){
       res.send('Username or Email already exist');
      }
      else {
        res.send('User created!!!')
      }
    });
  }
    
});
   //User login Route
   //http://localhost:8080/api/authenticate
   router.post('/authenticate',function(req,res) {
       res.send('Testing the route');
   });

  return router;
}
```

and finally HTTP requester output (it is working fine for register api in /app/models/api.js)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason seems to be this:

```
app.use('/app',appRoutes);
```

This adds your routes with a prefix of `/app`, which should be `/api`:

```
app.use('/api', appRoutes);
```